# C# SQL Row delete parent with child rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I have a program where I am writing data into datagridviews and when I'm closing form data is saved to SQL Server database. But I have a problem deleting parent row when it have child rows. I am getting Concurrency violation exception. When I check database I see child rows deleted only.

Here is my query for creating SQL Server tables:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE Auto("
                        + "VIN varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + "Make nvarchar(50),"
                        + "Model nvarchar(50),"
                        + "Year smallint);";
```

and

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE Repair("
                        + "ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + "VIN varchar(10) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Description nvarchar(255),"
                        + "Cost float)"
                        + "ALTER TABLE Repair ADD FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Auto(VIN) ON DELETE CASCADE;";
```

I am updating database via a `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me,here is the fiddle

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cafba/1)

Do you have a trigger by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

I dont get why you use ALTER TABLE try something like this it works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE Auto(
VIN varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Make nvarchar(50),
Model nvarchar(50),
Year smallint
);

CREATE TABLE Repair(
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
VIN varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(255),
Cost float,
FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Auto(VIN) ON DELETE CASCADE)
);
```

Delete Example:

```
DELETE FROM Auto WHERE VIN = 'BMW';
```